# Entity Framework ==> Options in different app.configs

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, mvvm, entity

currently I try to create a Database-project via MVVM-pattern and Entity-Framework(Database first).
I've three class libraries (View, Logic, Data). My StartUp Project is View, so this app.config is used. Problem is, that the connectionString and the invariant names from the provider are stored in the app.config from the Data-library. 
I can't store it into the other app.config(View), so what can I do?

App.Config (View):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.1.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

App.Config (Data):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=19.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=19.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=19.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="19.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=blablablaService))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=licence;Password=1111;Data Source=carlo_db" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.DBModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=CARLO_DB;USER ID=LICENCE;PASSWORD=blablabla;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MainContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.DBModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=CARLO_DB;PASSWORD=blablabla;USER ID=LICENCE&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I can neither write the data in the app.config of the View (OracleManagedDataAccess and EF aren't installed there), nor i can define Data as StartUp.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why can't you move the configuration to the `App.config` of the executable (the view project) where it belongs?

Comment: The config section is "entityFramework". This package is installed in the Data-Library. So I get an exception that this section is unknown (If I write the config in the View-App.Config).

Comment: Reference the package from the view project as well then. You'll still need the EF assemblies at runtime.

Comment: That wouldn't be MVVM anymore, would it? Isn't it possible to pass these properties outside the app.config?

Comment: What? Your issue has nothing to do with MVVM. You could create the connection string programmatially, but if you want to use configuration it goes in the executable app.

Comment: Ok, I have already managed to create the ConnectionString like this. But I don't know (and I haven't found anything on that) how to set the provider:
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"